# Intent not started, JavaCameraView (OpenCV) doesn't stop

Tags: android, opencv

I have a problem with my application. One of my activity isn't started in a given configuration. My app uses open CV to detect facial features. The images uses by openCV can be Bitmaps or frames from a CameraView. ***Everything is working fine when I'm working on Bitmaps***. But when I'm using the camera, the activity is not started and I can't figure out why. I'm using the same code to start the activity in both cases.

I tried to add several flags including

- FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)

So I can see that the intent is triggered (new task animation) but the onCreate from the new activity is never called.

The logcat doesn't show anything, at least no errors.

```
I/System.out﹕ creates camera profile
I/System.out﹕ displayEcranProfil
I/System.out﹕ after startactivity
D/JavaCameraView﹕ Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1806336
I/FdActivity﹕ onPause
D/JavaCameraView﹕ Disconnecting from camera
D/JavaCameraView﹕ Notify thread
D/JavaCameraView﹕ Wating for thread
I/System.out﹕ Processing finished
```

And the code executed is the following:

```
...
else {
    System.out.println("creates camera profile");
    displayEcranProfil();
}
System.out.println("Processing finished");

...
private void displayEcranProfil() {
    System.out.println("displayEcranProfil");
    Intent intent = new Intent(FdActivity.this, EcranProfil.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    System.out.println("after startactivity");
}
```

The app just freeze and a black screen is displayed after a few seconds. The debugger doesn't show anything unexpected.

I have been working on bitmaps for a few weeks, and I detected this bug yesterday when i tried to use the camera again. Everything was working fine before. Something might freeze the app but I don't know why.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

**Edit :**

The JavaCameraView from openCV seems to be the source of the problem. I should see the following logs

```
D/JavaCameraView﹕ Finish processing thread
I/FdActivity﹕ onCameraViewStopped
I/System.out﹕ On Create EcranProfil
```

But it seems that the JavaCameraView thread keeps running ..

Comment: Did you declare appropriate camera permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes, I've been working on this project for months, the camera works fine. I have been working on bitmaps for a few weeks, and I detected this bug yesterday when i tried to use the camera again. Everything was working fine before. Something might freeze the app but I don't know why

Comment: Would you mind posting some code of your EcranProfil class? At least the oncreate? Something interesting im seeing in the logcat is that the two  system.out.println calls happen with nothing in between. Try to have a system.out.println in the oncreate of your EcranProfil class and thatll help debug it

Comment: There is already a syso in the EcranProfil's onCreate. This class is working fine when i'm not using the camera. I can't start any Activity at this point. Even a finish() call doesn't work.